# is it possible to make c++ standard sort stable using custom comparators and if i does not want to use stable_sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

[problem link](https://leetcode.com/problems/rearrange-words-in-a-sentence/%5C)

I was solving this problem and I created a custom comparator to the first sort based on the length and then on basis of the index to sort it stable using standard c++ sort. But this custom comparator does not sort with stable order. and when I used stable_sort it got accepted. I am curious why a custom comparator can't be used to sort stabily.

```
  class Solution {
 public:
    string arrangeWords(string text) {
    stringstream ss(text);
    string word;
    vector<pair<int,int>>v;
    int ind=0;
    unordered_map<int,string>temp;
    while(ss>>word){
        int n=word.length();
        transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
        v.push_back({n,ind});
        temp[ind]=word;
        ind++;
        
    }
    auto cmp=[](pair<int,int>a,pair<int,int>b){
        if(a.first==b.first){
            return a.second<b.second;
        }
       return a.first<b.first;  
    };
    stable_sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cmp);
    //   for(auto elem:v){
    //     cout<<elem.first<<" "<<elem.second<<"\n";
    // }
    string res="";
    for(auto x:v){
        
        res+=(temp[x.second]+" ");
    }
    int n=res.size();
    res.erase(res.begin()+n-1);
    res[0]=toupper(res[0]);
    return res;

   }
};
```

this work but if I use a custom comparator with just standard sort it does not preserve order even after writing in custom comparator which is

```
static bool cmp(pair<int,int>p1,pair<int,int>p2){
    if(p1.first==p2.first){
        p1.second<p2.second;
    }
    return p1.first<p2.first;
 }
```

Comment: The stability does not depend on the comparator but on the algorithm. Nobody has found a stable in-place O(n*lg(n)) sorting algorithm yet, as far as I know.

Comment: "_... but if I use a custom comparator with just standard sort it does not preserve order  ..."_ this is correct and why there is `std::stable_sort`.  _"...The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: If it was possible to perform a stable sort using `std::sort` without any compromise, then `std::stable_sort` would not exist in the first place.